# How to monitor GraphQL request like monitor Rest API with Charles

Tags: graphql, charles-proxy

How to monitor GraphQL request  like monitor Rest API with Charles  ?

I'd like to monitor request with my application's GraphQL request,

But only get some Rest request from my application in Charles

Is that possible to monitor GraphQL Request ? How ?

**PS:**

1. Api works fine, I just want to check API network speed via Charles
2. I have setup the wifi proxy of iPhone device to connect my computer as Charles proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

If requests aren't appearing in Charles, this isn't an issue related to GraphQL. Charles doesn't actually know anything about REST specifically, and will happily show the raw data of GraphQL requests just the same.

This is likely caused by an unrelated issue in your application, which isn't sending traffic via Charles' proxy, or isn't sending your requests to the network at all.

Comment: I can see endpoint of Rest API of my app, just  didn't seen my GraphQL endpoint in Charles,  do you mean I must miss some setting for this case ?

Comment: By the way, api works fine, I just want to check API network speed via Charles.

Comment: There's no special settings required for GraphQL. For some reason, your traffic isn't being sent via Charles proxy at all. That probably means you're using a different HTTP client for GraphQL, and that client isn't using your proxy settings.

Comment: Do you mean graphQL can bypass the setting in iOS devices' wifi setting ?  I have setup the proxy setting in iPhone's wifi  proxy setting.

Comment: @JerryZhou Flutter apps for example definitely can and will bypass device's proxy setting if using dio library.